# How to hide a method in my subclass?

Tags: objective-c-2.0

I'm creating a class by subclassing and I have a method that I use to configure the object that should not be used by users of the class. Is there a way to hide this method or make it private?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to declare a method as private in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647079/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-method-as-private-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to keep the method out of the class's declaration, so that it's not visible by inspecting the header file, but you really can't completely hide a method. At the extreme, a determined developer can easily query the runtime to get an object's class, and from there the list of methods provided by the class.

Convention and trust are two big factors that guide Objective-C development. Probably the best way to prevent clients from calling your setup method without tying yourself and your code in knots is to put a big warning in the documentation: "This method is for internal use only, and should not be called by client code."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The best like you said by extending the class using a unnamed category like is specified by Apple's Objective C 2.0 documentation