# No declaration of property error in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I wonder what is wrong with this?

.h file:

```
typedef enum {
    N4LoupeTypeRound,
    N4LoupeTypeRectangle,
} N4LoupeType;

@interface N4LoupeLayer : CALayer {
    N4LoupeType _type;
    UIView *_originalView;
    CALayer *_mask;
    CALayer *_overlay;
}

@property (nonatomic) N4LoupeType type;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIView *originalView;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "N4LoupeLayer.h"

@interface N4LoupeLayer (Privates)

@property (nonatomic, retain) CALayer *mask;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CALayer *overlay;

@end

@implementation N4LoupeLayer

@synthesize type = _type;
@synthesize originalView = _originalView;
@synthesize mask = _mask;
@synthesize overlay = _overlay; // ******I GET THE ERROR HERE********* 

@end
```

No declaration of property 'overlay' found in the interface in N4LoupeLayer.m

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743586/synthesizing-properties-in-categories

Comment: Thanks for the link: Indeed the problem is the same. I should use Extensions and not Categories for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined the properties for the `Privates`category, but you are trying to synthesize them in `N4LoupeLayer`.

Comment: I just realized that I want a class extension and not a category. I should write @interface N4LoupeLayer () instead of @interface N4LoupeLayer (Privates) in the .m file.
Even though, this is strange yet. why the error does not appear in _mask property?

Comment: When you don't use any categories, simply write `@interface N4LoupeLayer`. The reason of why you just see the error reported for `_overlay` is that probably the properties are handled in LIFO order.