# How to add properties to NSMutableArray via category extension?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, subclass

I know that I can "subclass" an NSMutableArray using "category extensions," i.e. `@interface NSMutableArray (MyExtension)`, to add new functions to the class. However, is there a way using category extensions to also add new *properties* to the extension?

Answer (score 1):

Note that  `@interface NSMutableArray (MyStuff)` is a *category* and not a *class extension*.   They are similar in this context, but actually do have quite a few different details.

You can't add storage to an existing class through either mechanism.  You can use [Associative References](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAssociativeReferences.html) to associate data with an instance, though.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, categories can add only methods to a class, not ivars.  You could declare `property` and `setProperty:` methods in the category, but I'm not sure where you'd store the actual data of your pseudo-property.