# Objective-C property that is readonly publicly, but has a private setter

Tags: objective-c, properties

I'd like to use the `@property` syntax to declare a synthesized property that is publicly readonly but has a setter that can be called privately from within the class.

Since it's Objective-C, this basically means that the `setFoo:` method would be synthesized, but calling it outside of the class itself would result in a warning (unrecognized selector). To trigger the warning I have to declare the property `readonly`; is there any way to force a synthesized setter that is only available within the class?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I think what you're looking for are called class extensions.  You would declare the property read-only in the header:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
}

@property (readonly, assign) NSInteger myInteger;

@end
```

Then redeclare in your class extension in the implementation file:

```
@interface MyClass ()

@property (readwrite, assign) NSInteger myInteger;

@end


@implementation MyClass

@end
```

For more check out Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3)

Comment: You're correct, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743586/synthesizing-properties-in-categories/3251621#3251621

Comment: This is a great way to leverage the convenience of properties while maintaining necessary encapsulation. :) Love this capability.

Comment: Updated documentation link: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3

Comment: Did anyone actually test this?  Attempting to set the property using dot notation gets a compiler error (good), but using the setMyInteger: method only gets a compiler warning, and when the app is run the "readonly" property does get changed.

Comment: @jk7 That is correct behavior;   the compiler is telling you you are doing it wrong.  The runtime is "free" to violate this.

Answer (score 1):

I might be late, but without extension i did using the following technique

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
 NSString * name;
}

@property (readonly, strong) NSString * name;

@end
```

on the other hand in implementation file

```
@implementation MyClass
 @synthesize name;

 - (id)initWithItems:(NSDictionary *)items {
self = [super init];
if(self)
{ 
  name = @"abc";
}

return self;
}

@end
```

doing so it will set your value and will be accessible as readonly.
Thanks.