# How to make a public getter and private setter property with obj-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C property that is readonly publicly, but has a private setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008060/objective-c-property-that-is-readonly-publicly-but-has-a-private-setter)

Is there a way to make a synthesized property this way?

I really want to keep using the setter internally because of the retain/release it gives us, but i don't want this setter exposed to the world.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question: [Objective-C property that is readonly publicly, but has a private setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008060/objective-c-property-that-is-readonly-publicly-but-has-a-private-setter)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a readonly synthesized property.