# Assignment to readonly property error iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, ios6, attributes

I have a Singleton class called Constants and I need to set some app wide constants in there. Id like these constants to be readonly. So I did the following in the Constants.h file

```
 @interface Constants : NSObject
 {

 }

 @property (nonatomic, readonly)double U_LAT;
 @property (nonatomic, readonly)double U_LNG;
```

Then in my .m fileI got this method

```
 -(id)init
 {
     self = [super init];

     self.U_LAT = 49.2765;
     self.U_LNG = -123.2177;

     return self;
 }
```

I get this error from this code:

```
 Assignment to readonly property
```

Can I not initialize my readonly variable in the init method? If not how do I initialize them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`self.propertyName = val;` is the same as `[self setPropertyName:val];` -- it requires a setter method to exist. Read-only properties don't have setter methods.

You can set the ivar which backs the property directly, however:

```
-(id)init
 {
     self = [super init];

     _U_LAT = 49.2765;
     _U_LNG = -123.2177;

     return self;
 }
```

The ivar's name will be the property name prefixed with an underscore if you are allowing the properties to be synthesized automatically. If you have an explicit `@synthesize propName;`, the ivar will have the same name. You can also create a variable with any name you like, again using a synthesize statement: `@synthesize cat = dog;`

It's also possible for the property to be read-only publicly, but be writeable by the class; this involves either declaring a setter method in a class extension or [redeclaring the property in the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008060/objective-c-property-that-is-readonly-publicly-but-has-a-private-setter?rq=1).

Answer (score 5):

I think the better way is to redeclare the property in a private interface, like this:

```
// .h

@interface Constants : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, readonly) double U_LAT;
@end

// .m

@interface Constants ()
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) double U_LAT;
@end
```

And yes, in inits and dealloc, refer directly to the variable as _U_LAT.

Comment: Or better refer to them as `self.U_LAT`.

Comment: Zaph: it is strongly discouraged to use accessor methods (`self.foo`) during init.  Better to use the underscore variable, `_foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Better still to declare them not as properties but as constants.

In the `.h` file, add the following code above the `@interface`:

```
extern double const U_LAT;
extern double const U_LNG;
```

Then in the `.m` file, add the following code above the `@interface`:

```
double const U_LAT = 49.2765;
double const U_LNG = -123.2177;
```

The `U_LAT` and `U_LNG` will be available to any class that imports `Constants.h`, and you won't have to deal with properties or interfaces.

It's for exactly this sort of thing that `const` was invented.