# what is protocol in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, interface, protocols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981832/what-is-a-protocol)

hi,

how to use protocol in Objective-c ? what is the advantage of it .?

Thank and regards+

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Protocols have many advantages. The idea is to provide a way for classes to share the same method and property declarations without inheriting them from a common ancestor. This is especially useful in Objective-C when using the [delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern), on which the iOS and Mac OS SDKs rely heavily. There's plenty of information out there on the subject, including a good overview [in Apple's developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-SW1).