# self.tableView.delegate = self Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, uicollectionview

If I have a UIViewController and I hook up a tableView to it in storyboards, connect the tableview outlet, and then connect the datasource and delegate methods via the connections inspector (cntrl+drag to vc orange circle icon), do I still need to add `self.tableView.delegate = self` and `self.tableView.datasource = self` to the actual view controller? Of course in the actual vc I'm implementing the tableView data/delegate protocols.

Also I'm assuming whatever the answer is the same would go for a collection view controller being connected via storyboard the same way?

What are the pros and cons of adding it?

```
class FooController:UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.datasource = self
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { ... }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { ... }

}
```

Comment: Based on you tagging the question with protocols it seems that are slightly confused about protocol vs. delegate. Most iOS developers get confused about it initially. I recommend you see this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39457213/5175709)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> do I still need to add self.tableView.delegate = self to the actual view controller?

No. You are doing this by making the connection in the storyboard. They are *exactly* the same thing: an assignment to the `delegate` property, expressed in two different ways (one in code, one "graphically" in Interface Builder). You only need to do one of them.

But if your view controller were a table view *controller* (UITableViewController subclass), then you would do *neither*, because the table view controller is *already* the table view's data source and delegate. The same is true for a collection view *controller* (UICollectionViewController subclass); it is *already* the collection view's data source and delegate.

Answer (score 3):

I usually set `delegate` and `dataSource` programmatically in View Controller's `viewDidLoad` method.
Because sometimes I missed to set them in nib or I created my table view by coding.

As Matt's answer, they're the same. You can pick one way to make you happy.
Happy coding, bro /.

Answer (score 0):

I am agreed with both Matt and Quang answer but sometimes we need to reuse same tableview and its delegate & data source in other ViewController class at that time connection with outlet for datasource and delegate might not be work thatmeans your delegates methods might not be called .

Example -

I have a ViewController(class A) with a tableview.I need to reuse this controler whole view to another class (Class B)

A.view.addSubview(B.view)

So in this case you must need to write below codes

```
Class A:UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.tableView.delegate = self
      self.tableView.datasource = self 
   }


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
{


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  }
```