# What are the key reasons for using @protocols in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-protocol

Why would I want to use a protocol rather than create a subclass and inherit the methods..?

Please explain it to me, i'm to confused about this topic, i'm not very pleased with the explanation in the book im reading.

Where do I use protocols instead of other ways to get the methods..? if I can subclass a class and get the methods why would i want to use a protocol where i need to define the methods?

Comment: There's lots of other explanations out there. Can you elaborate on what you do and don't understand?

Comment: Where do I use protocols instead of other ways to get the methods..? if I can subclass a class and get the methods why would i want to use a protocol where i need to define the methods? @JoshCaswell

Comment: Please edit your question to elaborate.

Comment: no, it's not a duplicate. im not asking what is it. why is it better then, and where is it more commonly to be used @JoshCaswell

Comment: Without the explanation of _exactly_ what you don't understand, the only way anyone can reply is by giving a full description.

Comment: I agree that what a protocol/interface is and why you'd choose interfaces over inheritance are not the same question. More importantly, although the answers to [What is a Protocol?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3981832/643383) do a good job of explaining *what*, they really don't address *why*. Voting to reopen, although it wouldn't surprise me if there's some other, more duplicative duplicate out there already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why would I want to use a protocol rather than create a subclass and
>   inherit the methods..?

Protocols make it possible for unrelated classes to all implement the same interface. Instances of each of those classes can then be used by a client of the protocol. For example, `UITableViewDataSource` is a protocol that provides an interface by which a table can ask for data from any object that implements the protocol. The table view doesn't care what the type of the object is so long as it implements the data source interface.

Imagine how unpleasant things would be if all table data sources had to inherit from a common class! Objective-C only provides single inheritance, so you'd effectively be constrained to using only a single kind of object for your data source. With protocols, though, a data source can be a view controller, a model object, or perhaps even a remote object.

To be more specific, protocols allow a form of *polymorphism*. That means that a single object can take several forms: e.g. view controller, table data source, table delegate, scroll view delegate. Because Objective-C is a single-inheritance language, you only get one of those interfaces via inheritance. The rest you implement yourself, but that often makes sense because you generally adopt a given protocol in order to customize some other object's behavior anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Because subclassing and protocols are two different things. Subclassing extends a class with new functionality while inheriting all previous functionality of a specific class while a protocol, when applied to a class, simply adds functionality to it and doesn't inherit anything from it; what that class is usually doesn't matter.

Protocols are most frequently used for the delegate pattern in Objective-C whereby an object can send a message to another object without caring WHAT that object is (i.e. it's class).

Often times, a delegate is declared as:

```
 @property(nonatomic, assign) id < MyObjectDelegate > delegate;
```

Notice that the class of the property is `id` -- in essence, you don't care if the object is a car or a turtle -- all you need to know is that it is an object (`id`) and that it contractually subscribes to the functions you need it to. So if your delegate is type `turtle`, you can call [delegate myStateChanged]; or, if your delegate is a car, you can call [delegate myStateChanged]. All you need to know is that, if you send a message to it, it will accept it.

I would look up and read about the use of Objective-C delegates as I think it will really help you understand protocols better and how it's different than subclassing. I don't know if you're familiar with other, object-oriented programming languages, but if so, protocols are most similar to Interfaces in other languages.

Comment: Protocols do not add any functionality to a class. A protocol only defines an abstract interface.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that is true, but I couldn't think of a better way to state it. The idea is roughly equivalent though -- it provides a way for a class to handle some message

Comment: I reworded it to state "when applied to a class" because yes, by itself, a protocol does nothing but define.

Comment: No, a class implements functionality regardless of whether it happens to implement methods that are also defined in some protocol or not. The protocol is just a way to abstract out the implementation and to state - this object has a certain set of methods.

Comment: @CJ_912 thanks allot buddy. The next subject in the book is about delegates :)

Comment: @CJ_912 Applying a protocol to a class does not add any functionality to the class. The class would work exactly the same without the protocol. Applying a protocol to a class is simply a marker telling other classes that the class has a certain interface.

Comment: I don't think I've ever stated that a class doesn't implement any functionality before an interface is applied to it -- only that the interface itself adds publicly defined message to the class to which it is applied while not inheriting the functionality of the class itself.

Comment: @CJ_912 No, a protocol adds nothing. You keep saying that a protocol adds functionality and now you say it add "publicly defined message" to a the class. It does neither. Remove the protocol and the class doesn't change in any way. Add the protocol and the class doesn't change in any way. It is simply a marker.

Answer (score -2):

Protocols are useful because you can implement many protocols, instead you can only extend a single class.

Comment: Many classes can extend a single class.  The net result is the same.  Can you elaborate?