# Obj-c noob question regarding subclassing with non-void return type?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Lets say i create a class, MasterClass and then create another 4 classes that each subclass MasterClass and I want each subclass to implement a specific method which returns an object. The MasterClass itself is more of a shell class with common utility methods, etc.. What is the correct format to use instead of:

```
// implemented by subclass
-(MyObject*)doSomething{}
```

which obv throws a compiler error?

thx

Comment: Just return `nil` in that method…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing in Object Oriented languages is called an [abstract class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_type). Objective-C does not support abstract classes.  You can however, declare the method in the superclass and have its implementation throw an exception.  This will force your subclasses to override it and implement the desired behavior.

See this post from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034373/creating-an-abstract-class-in-objective-c).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but here's a shot: You want to define your interface like this:

```
@interface Subclass1 : MasterClass
```

Then implement your method as usual.
declaration:

```
-(MyObject*)doSomething;
```

implementation:

```
-(MyObject*)doSomething{

//Stuff...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's what i use in the case of a explicit subclass structure:

```
@class MyObject;

@interface MONBase : NSObject

/* required override */
-(MyObject *)doSomething;

/* ... */

@end

@implementation MONBase

/* ... */ 

-(MyObject*)doSomething
{
    assert(0 && "this override is required");
    return nil;
}

@end
```

*however*... protocols are often generally more useful in these and similar cases. the following exhibits one way to achieve this. it implements a protocol and inherits from the shared base -- use derived from the usage in the OP:

```
@class MyObject;

@protocol MONProtocol

/* required overrides: */
@required
- (MyObject *)doSomething;

/* optional overrides: */
@optional

@end

/* base, with shared implementation */
@interface MONBase : NSObject
@end

@implementation MONBase

- (MyObject *)doSomething
{
    /*
    as long as the sig matches, you won't need to declare it in the interface -- that may be a good thing.
    you may prefer *not* to implement this, if you favor a runtime exception
    */
    assert(0 && "this MONProtocol override is required");
    return nil;
}

@end

/* subclass of MONBase which extends by implementing MONProtocol */
@interface MONSub : MONBase <MONProtocol>
{
    MyObject* theIvar; /* << simplest case implementation */
}

@end

@implementation MONBase

/* ... */

- (MyObject *)doSomething
{
    return [[theIvar retain] autorelease];
}

@end
```

protocols are nice because they provide many benefits of multiple inheritance, and provide very little dependencies.