# How to create Abstract class in obj-C for iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, class, abstract

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating an abstract class in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034373/creating-an-abstract-class-in-objective-c)

Hi

Can any one please help me create abstract class in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered:

[Creating an abstract class in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034373/creating-an-abstract-class-in-objective-c)