# Is NSObject is Abstract class in Objective-C? But we can create instance of NSObject, then how does it follow the rule of Abstract class?

Tags: objective-c

Which class is Abstract class in Objective-C, I have read some doc where NSObject is Abstract class, but we can create instance of NSObject, then how it is follow the abstract class rule.

```
NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];    
NSLog(@"description = %@",[obj description]);    
NSLog(@"class name = %@",[obj class]);
```

Please advice.

And also I heard another one Abstract Class in Objective-C, what is the name of the class?

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C has no compile time restraint against instantiating abstract classes. See [Creating an abstract class in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034373/creating-an-abstract-class-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C there is no language level concept of an abstract class. You have to read the documentation for a class to find out if it should be treated as an abstract class. There are a few such classes in Cocoa, e.g. `NSObject`, `NSProxy` and `NSOperation`. It's more common for behaviour to be defined in protocols rather than in abstract classes.

The Cocoa framework contains to root classes (i.e. class which do not have superclasses). `NSObject` is one root class and `NSProxy` is the other. `NSProxy` does not implement an `init` method which means an exception is raised when you attempt to create an instance.