# is NSObject an abstract class?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is NSObject is Abstract class in Objective-C? But we can create instance of NSObject, then how does it follow the rule of Abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585829/is-nsobject-is-abstract-class-in-objective-c-but-we-can-create-instance-of-nsob)

I have studied in some tutorial that NSobject is an abstract class.But when we create an object and call methods ,it is working fine.basically we cant create objects directly to abstract class.how can we say it is an abstract class.

Comment: I use \@protocol with \@required

Comment: hi,why we use \ before @ symbol?