# Custom Framework to external class

Tags: objective-c, ios, frameworks, abstract-class, external

I been creating a nice static custom framework for my project using this useful [Guide](http://codefriend.blogspot.de/2011/09/creating-ios-framework-with-xcode4.html)

but now i realize that it need to get access of few methods of an **External Class**.

So how to deal with this?
Should i create an Abstract Interface like showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034373/creating-an-abstract-class-in-objective-c) and put it inside the framework?
So i can access to some fews methods of this *external class* ?

Or should i proceed in some other ways? like using some *framework dependencies*?

Did someone have ever had this situation before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved using the Design Patterns like **Abstract Interface Factory** as showed [Here](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html)!