# Abstract class for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, abstract-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating an abstract class in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034373/creating-an-abstract-class-in-objective-c)

I'd like to make abstract class in Objective-C project.

But, I can't find ideas suchlike 'abstract'(in java), 'virtual'(in c++).

Doesn't Objective-C have an abstract idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Formally, no. Abstract classes are implemented by stubbing out methods in the base class and then documenting that a subclass must implement those methods. The onus is on the author to write classes that match the class contract rather than on the compiler to check for missing methods.

Objective-C has *protocols*, which are like Java interfaces. If you're looking for the equivalent to a *pure virtual* C++ class or an *interface* in Java, this is what you want.

Comment: I'd go further in saying that Objective-C really doesn't *do* abstract classes.  Use protocols, which support Objective-C's duck-typing ideals, rather than C++'s common base class ones.

Comment: You can force overriding of key methods by having the base class implement them to throw a descriptive exception.

Comment: @WadeTregaskis: In well-formed Objective-C, I'd expect heavy use of protocols and avoidance of these sorts of *faux*-C++ features. That said, production Objective-C is (sadly) usually written by people who know plenty of C++ and not much Objective-C. Might as well put it in terms that those engineers understand.

Answer (score 12):

There are no abstract classes but you can produce something similar using a combination of a *class* and a *protocol* (which is similar to Java's *interface*). First divide up your abstract class into those methods you wish to provide default implementations for and those you require sub-classes to implement. Now declare the default methods in an `@interface` and implement them in an `@implementation`, and declare the required methods in an `@protocol`. Finally derive your sub-classes from `class<protocol>` - a class which implements the protocol. For example:

```
@interface MyAbstract

- (void) methodWithDefaultImplementation;

@end

@protocol MyAbstract

- (void) methodSubclassMustImplement;

@end

@implementation MyAbstract

- (void) methodWithDefaultImplementation { ... }

@end

@interface MyConcreteClass: MyAbstract<MyAbstract>
   ...
@end

@implementation MyConcreteClass

// must implement abstract methods in protocol
- (void) methodSubclassMustImplement { ... }

@end
```

If you are concerned over using the same name for a class and a protocol look at Cocoa where `NSObject` follows this pattern...

HTH

Comment: Problem I'm finding is that if I call super on any of these methods, then I get the warning "[super class] may not respond to '[method name].'" The only way I can get rid of this warning is to implement the protocol in the abstract class too. But if I do, they effectively become public methods which defeats the object...

Comment: @jowie - I don't understand what you are trying to do. The super class does not implement the abstract methods, that is the point - all the subclasses implement the abstract methods. What do you expect a call to super for an abstract method to do?

Comment: I guess I'm probably not using the Abstract model correctly. I want my superclass to do all of the default case stuff, but then for my subclass to override certain methods, add their own stuff and be able to call super for the default stuff.

Comment: @jowie - you are describing normal inheritance. You just declare all the methods in the base class and provide default implementations for them. Any derived class can override a base class method and invoke the base class implementation using `super`.

Comment: yeah - I guess I just have to make them public because there is no protected in obj-c.

Comment: @jowie - You are correct, there are no protected *methods* in Obj-C. However there are patterns, e.g. using categories and multiple header files, which provide similar semantics at *compile time*. Go google, and if you have questions over an answer you find you can always ask it on SO.

Comment: This is really a great idea to mimic abstract class...

Comment: @CRD I cannot call `methodSubclassMustImplement` inside `methodWithDefaultImplementation` unless  `MyAbstract` class conforms to `MyAbstract` protocol. Isn't that the whole point of abstract classes? If the abstract class conforms to the protocol, then I will get a warning `method not implemented` in the abstract class.

Comment: @mostruash you can make a private .h containing a category of your abstract class which implements the interface and then include that in your subclasses .m