# What is the proper way to lazy initialize an abstract property in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, superclass, lazy-initialization

In super class:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Foo *foo;
```

In sub class:

```
- (Foo *) foo
{
     if(!super.foo) super.foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
     return super.foo;
}
```

Does this make sense? Is it even a good idea to have abstract properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictly speaking, there is no "abstract class" or "abstract property" in Objective-C, see for example this thread [Creating an abstract class in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034373/creating-an-abstract-class-in-objective-c) for a good overview.

Your approach is not optimal, because it requires that the superclass implements `foo` and `setFoo:`, which contradicts the idea of "abstractness".

A better solution is to define a "dynamic property" in the superclass:

```
@interface SuperClass : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) Foo *foo;
@end

@implementation SuperClass
@dynamic foo;
@end
```

and explicitly synthesize it in the subclass:

```
@interface SubClass : SuperClass
@end

@implementation SubClass
@synthesize foo = _foo;
@end
```

Now you can access `foo` on a subclass object, but on a  superclass object it will cause a runtime exception.

For lazy initialization, you can use the usual pattern, without any "super-tricks":

```
- (Foo *) foo
{
    if(!_foo) _foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
    return _foo;
}
```

An **alternative approach** (also mentioned in above thread) is to use a "protocol" instead
of a common superclass:

```
@protocol HasFoo <NSObject>
- (Foo *)foo;
@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject<HasFoo>
@property(strong, nonatomic) Foo *foo;
@end

@implementation SubClass
- (Foo *) foo
{
    if(!_foo) _foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
    return _foo;
}
@end
```

Comment: Thank you Martin. I am still learning to think in Obj-C. This makes a lot of sense.