# Is it possible to create warnings for methods that must be overridden?

Tags: objective-c, clang, pragma

I was reading [Creating an abstract class in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034373/creating-an-abstract-class-in-objective-c), and I wasn't terribly satisfied with the fact that the "abstractness" of the class is only enforced at runtime. I'd like to be able to show some warnings if the method is not implemented in a subclass. Ideally, this could be condensed down to one or two `#define`s.

Is there a clever use of `__attribute((available,deprecated,etc))__` or a `#warning` with some careful `#pragma clang diagnostic push`es that can accomplish this?

I think this is possible; I just don't know enough about Clang to figure it out.

#### EDIT:

There's no need to tell me I should be using protocols. I already use them for this purpose. I'm more curious to see if it *can* be done (to learn more about Clang) than whether it *should* be done.

I see this working the in a similar way to `NSManagedObject` requiring properties to be marked `@synthesized` or `@dynamic`. I've researched this, and I see that in `NSManagedObject.h` the class is marked `NS_REQUIRES_PROPERTY_DEFINITIONS`, which translates to `__attribute__((objc_requires_property_definitions))` in `NSObjCRuntime.h`. Is there some creative use of these built-in `#define`s that could make this work?

#### EDIT #2:

For people saying that abstract superclasses are not the Objective-C way, I'll direct you to the [documentation for `UIMotionEffects`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIMotionEffect_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> #### Subclassing Notes
>
> This class is abstract and cannot be instantiated
> directly.

Comment: Good question. In Java for a while, people were proposing using aspects for this and having them generate warnings/errors that would be surfaced during compilation.

Comment: You can define a protocol, which delegates should be implementing its methods.

Comment: This is probably not what you're looking for, but you could define a protocol for the required methods, and make sure you define the subclass to conform to this protocol. That way the compiler will tell you what methods need to be implemented.

Comment: like told, use a protocol and you can define if something is `@required` or `@optional`

Comment: @JuJoDi that question says nothing about creating warnings

Comment: You can NSAssert if you'd like, but the point is that Objective-C isn't built to virtualize classes entirely like you're trying to do.  If you google Objective-C pure virtual class though, you'll find many attempts at a solution

Comment: @AlexanderPerechnev I could define a protocol, but the problem with that is that all subclasses need to implement the protocol, but the superclass doesn't. I'd just like to know how/if it's possible to make these warnings in the subclass if it doesn't implement the superclass method.

Comment: @JuJoDi NSAssert also doesn't give a compile-time warning, it throws a runtime exception

Comment: You're still attempting to use Objective-C in a way that it was not intended

Answer (score 4):

I prefer the [NSException](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSException_Class/Reference/Reference.html) approach (which is a run-time, not a compile time, error).

In your superclass:

```
@interface NSSuperclass : NSObject

- (void)execute;

@end


@implementation NSSuperclass

- (void)execute
{
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException
                                   reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Called %@ on superclass NSSuperclass, this should only be called on subclasses", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)]
                                 userInfo:@{@"object": self}];
}

@end
```

And then override this method in your subclasses.

Comment: you need to raise/throw it and you should use `_cmd` for method name

Comment: @BryanChen yeah, I made the edits.

Comment: This is the way I've seen a lot of system classes take. Stinks that there's no `__attribute__` for a compile-time warning, though.

Comment: Yeah it does, odd that there's one for requires super, but not for retires overriding. I guess they want you to use protocols.

Answer (score 3):

I go for [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html)

untested code, the idea is use protocol type (maybe combined with class type) instead of just class type.

```
@interface BaseClass : NSObject

- (void)foo;

@end

@protocol BaseClassProtocol : NSObject

@required
- (void)bar;

@end

@interface SubClass : BaseClass <BaseClassProtocol>

@end

@interface SubClass2 : BaseClass // no <BaseClassProtocol>

@end

// some code

BaseClass <BaseClassProtocol> * obj = [SubClass new]; // good
BaseClass <BaseClassProtocol> * obj = [SubClass2 new]; // warning
```

Comment: I guess this is the Objective-C way of doing things, but I already know about protocols and they're not what I was looking for

Comment: @paulrehkugler if you really want the C++ style abstract class, use Objective-C++ and use C++ pure virtual function with C++ class

Comment: What if a SubClass method needs to call [super bar]; ? It's a problem because BaseClass can't publicly implement the protocol because then it is no longer abstract, but it has to somewhere otherwise super bar can't be called inside SubClass. Maybe using a private class extension shared inside the SubClass.m?

Comment: @malhal there is no `[BaseClass bar]` method so it doesn't make sense to call `[super bar]` from subclass. Unless you want to call it from sub-subclass, which shouldn't have any issue.