# how to implement this scenario

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

I have class A, B and C with 2 methods in all 3 classes.

```
class A
- (void)onSuccess {
}

- (void)onFailure {
}
```

Then one `CommonClass` is there in which I’ll be doing some task. If class `A` is presenting `CommonClass` and after performing all the tasks I have to call either `onSuccess()` or `onFailure()` implemented in class `A`.

Which is the best way to do this, and how? In Java it's done by `extend` or `abstract` I guess.

Comment: Your question is very unclear to me. Please elaborate to clarify this and adjust your title to reflect the actual problem.

Comment: In Objective-C I believe you would define a Protocol, then you "implement" it by tacking onto your class definition by adding `<MyProtocol>`.  Protocols are synonymous to interfaces.  There are some vague concepts of "abstractness", but it's not inherent to the language like is is in Java.  See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034373/creating-an-abstract-class-in-objective-c

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It is not unclear.  In Java, you can create an abstract class, which is a hybrid Interface/Class where some methods are defined, some are not.  In Objective C, there is no direct way to do this.  OP is asking how would you implement something in Objective C that you would using abstract classes in Java.  Pretty clear question IMHO.

Comment: I'm with `JeroenVannevel` I think this is quite unclear and needs to be clarified more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly then it should be done with delegation. For exam:

```
//CommonClass.h

@protocol CommonDelegate <NSObject>
// list protocol methods...
- (void)onSuccess;
- (void)onFailure;
@optional

@interface CommonClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) id delegate;
-(void)Task;
@end

//CommonClass.m
#import "CommonClass.h"
@synthesize delegate;
-(void)Task
{
    if(do smth task){
        [delegate onSuccess];
    }
    else{
        [delegate onFailure]
    }
}


// ClassA.h
#import "CommonClass.h"

@interface ClassA : NSObject <CommonClassDelegate>
@end

// ClassA.m

-(void)init
{
    CommonClass *common = [[CommonClass alloc] init];
    common.delegate = self;
    [common Task];
}

- (void)onSuccess
{
    // do smth
}
- (void)onFailure
{
    // do smth
}
```

... Do the same for class B and C

Answer (score 1):

You can create a protocol class like this. This has only a .h file

```
@protocol RequestProtocolDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
    - (void)onSuccess;
    - (void)onFailure;
@end
```

and to use it in your class like this

file .h

```
#include "RequestProtocolDelegate.h"

@interface CommonClass : NSObject <RequestProtocolDelegate> {

}

@end
```

file .m

```
- (void)onSuccess {

}
- (void)onFailure {

}
```

Now you can use in your CommonClass this protocol