# Objective-c: How can I require override and not call super?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

I guess this is solved by writing a @protocol.

But I'm hungry for knowledge. Is there some flag or other way to require subclasses to override specific methods and not call super? Like the opposite of NS_REQUIRES_SUPER / objc_requires_super?

Comment: I have seen an NSAssert in the super class before which raises an exception if the superclass is called, might be one way of doing it.

Comment: Not sure but you can use category to override (however this is not appreciated). Also using swizzling.

Comment: I think what you'd have to do is test the class of the instance (with `isMemberOfClass`, not `isKindOfClass`) and throw an assertion if the class is not the same as the method's class.

Comment: @HotLicks and these tests could typically be done in `-init`?

Comment: You'd do the test in the method that was supposed to be overridden.

Comment: Well, then what's the difference between your suggestion and @Basheer_CAD 's suggestion?

Comment: His suggestion is doing the assert(NO) inevitably, which is fine if the superclass never stands on its own.  If the superclass is used on its own, however, you'd want the assertion to be conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do that in code not using any flags. 
- I add assertion in the method of the super class that needs to be overridden in case this method is get called

Here I have a class that have a method `fetchUserData` that should be overridden by the child class

```
- (void)fetchUserData
{
    NSString *descrip = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"child implementation for method:%@ :  %@",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),  NSStringFromClass([self class])
    NSAssert(NO, descrip);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some things [here](https://github.com/gnustep/gnustep-base/blob/master/Source/Additions/NSObject%2BGNUstepBase.m) that should be useful.

Specifically `subclassResponsibility:`

EDIT: Good point in the comments - GNUStep != Foundation. In other words, the methods on the page I linked to should be used with caution. However, I've personally used `subclassResponsibility:` and it works.

Comment: GNUStep != Foundation

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this right you're essentially asking how to make an abstract class... forcing subclasses to implement methods.

Check out : [Creating an abstract class in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1034373/1040049)

In short, have the method throw an exception.