# Why MKAnnotation is a protocol?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I didn't find any reason behind making MKAnnotation as a protocol. Looking for answer.

As it seems like an Abstract class to me.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: There is no direct concept of Abstract Class in Objective-C, so protocols is the answer to this.. see this thread, it might clear few questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034373/creating-an-abstract-class-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

Objective C does not have multiple inheritance.

Protocols allow implementation of a function(s) in classes that already have a different inheritance structure. Such as a protocol can be implemented by a ViewContoller, and often is.  If MKAnnotation was an abstract class, the implementation of the functions would have to be in a class that inherits from MKAnnotation.

Comment: I am trying to understand the reason that why MKAnnotation is a Protocol only, why not just a NSObject class.