# Unit test private class in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, white-box

How do you unit test a **private class** in Objective-C? Is it possible when both the `@interface` and the `@implementation` of the class are included in a .m implementation file?

Refactoring the interface of the private class into its own header is not allowed by the restrictions of the project.

This is a whole private class I would like to test, not [a private method of a public class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098550/unit-testing-of-private-methods-in-xcode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, duplicating the private interface in the test file is enough. Damn, Objective-C is  dangerous!

Comment: If you are allowed, you could use a #define to make it possible to #import the .m.  Something like #define INTERFACE_ONLY, then you use #ifdef to make the @implementation part not imported.

Comment: Isn't it the same in C? (This is a genuine question, not a rhetorical one)