# What does @interface DITableViewController (private) mean?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I found the following method in iOS SDK sample code:

```
@interface DITableViewController (private)
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;
@end
```

What does (private) means? is it the new syntax for Objective-C 2.0 (developed by Apple)?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is just a [category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360968/category-usage-in-objective-c). The syntax exist in ObjC 1.0 as well. "private" is the name of the category meaning "It is for private use only". This isn't a keyword.

Defining this category means instances of DITableViewController can be sent the message `-applicationDocumentsDirectory` as well, without modifying the class DITableViewController itself.

In ObjC 2.0, it may be better to use a class extension for category intended for private use.

```
@interface DITableViewController ()
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;
@end
```

(The linked answer provides much more detail.)

Comment: +1 for mentioning class extensions (aka anonymous categories).

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `(category)` is used as an alternative to subclassing. They provide a means to add methods to a class, even standard classes, like `NSString`.

http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1

Comment: You mention extending classes, but you forgot to mention that category methods can *replace* existing methods, whether you intend that to happen or not.